# How much progress has Israel made in eliminating (or capturing) Hamas' leadership by the end of January 2024?

Tags: 2023-israel-hamas-war, symbols, political-leaders

Similarly to what the US [did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most-wanted_Iraqi_playing_cards) in Iraq, Israel [issued](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/b1vyaaoht#:%7E:text=10%2C000%20unique%20decks%20of%20cards,its%20military%20wing%20Mohammed%20Deif.) a "pack of cards" with the Hamas leaders they intend eliminated (or captured). At the beginning of December, 10 had already been checked off, according to the 2nd source. How much progress have Israeli forces made towards achieving that objective as of the end January 2024?

Answer (score -1):

The conflict Between  Hamas and Israel is a proxy war between the Islamic Republic of Iran(and its proxies that are called the axis of resistance by the Islamic Republic)and Israel, apart from Hamas commanders Many Hezbollah and IRGC high ranking members have been eliminated.

Recently Israel [assassinated Saleh al-Arouri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Saleh_al-Arouri) the deputy leader of Hamas on 2 January. But Israel's main success was the elimination of [Sadegh Omidzadeh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadegh_Omidzadeh)(the head of IRGC intelligence service in Syria) and four other high ranking Iranian generals on 20 January. Some other examples are:

- Assassination of [Razi Mousavi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Razi_Mousavi) an IRGC general on 25 December.
- [Wissam al_tawil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wissam_al-Tawil), a Lebanese militant and senior commander of Hezbollah's Radwan Force on 8 January.

Comment: I'm not the one who DV, but this answer is pretty vague. They seem to have made progress, but you only mention 2 Hamas guys. The IRGC guys were probably not in the deck. I take your [implicit] point that Israel has a broader list of enemies [than Hamas], but it's a bit besides what I'm asking.

Comment: ^^ s/IRGC/IRGC & Hezbollah/

Comment: Yes I think the war isn't only between Hamas and Israel but it's between Israel and what the Islamic Republic calls *axis of resistance*, that's to say Hezbollah, Hams, Houthis and IRGC. Besides I had misspelled the word axis.

Comment: Yeah, but Israel probably doesn't expect to finish off the IRGC and Hezbollah leadership (too) in order to win their campaign in Gaza.